# ffmpeg3 encoding H.264 the log says undefined symbol: x264_encoder_open_148

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I just update to FFMPEG 3

When I try to convert a video to H.264 .mp4 :

```
$call_mp4 ->/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i __path_to_source__ -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 160k -r 30 -s 640x360 __path_to_output__.mp4 1> __path_to_log__.txt 2>&1
```

the log says

> /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined symbol:
>   x264_encoder_open_148

Is someone knows why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installed version of x264 does not match the version ffmpeq was linked against.

Comment: Hi I re-compiled ffmpeg and now it's fixed ;)